# Why do I get a core dump when running Irb or Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, crouton-os

I get a core dump when running `irb` or `ruby` at the command-line:

```
me@localhost:~$ irb
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
me@localhost:~$ ruby
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
me@localhost:~$ sudo irb
me@localhost:~$
me@localhost:~$ sudo ruby
me@localhost:~$
```

I'm running on ChromeOS dualboot with crouton using trusty and xfce.

I'm not sure how to begin fixing this. I assume that a language straight of the box, installed using

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

will work.

The same thing may be happening with Heroku: the segmentation fault and non-responsive `sudo` command is the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, create a title that is indicative of the problem. "Why won't Ruby respond?" tells us absolutely nothing. Instead, "Why do I get core dumps running Irb or Ruby?" would be useful and tell us something. Also, please read the help for formatting documents. It helps us help you when we can easily tell what are commands, code and text. Click the "?" in the header for the edit box then go to "Advanced help" for full information.

Comment: I thought I had figured that out: googling said segmentation faults can be caused by lack of permissions. Running as sudo doesn't make it core dump. If I have to run ruby as sudo, I don't mind. If I can't make Ruby respond, I have an issue.
Thank you for the formatting help.